# outlook.com calendar and contacts sync

Tags: email, contacts, calendar, exchange-activesync, hotmail

I recently started using a mac, and my mind was blown by the fact that I can't sync my live.com calendar with the default calendar app (same goes for contacts). I don't understand why this is the case since I can do these things on the iPhone...

I'd like to either,

1. Find a way to sync my calendar with the NATIVE apple apps (that doesn't involve first sharing the calendar with a gmail, then importing the gmail in to iCal (that's a stone age solution.))

or

1. Find a tool that works with ALL of the following (because I have 2 mail, cal, and contact accounts). 
   ﻿

   - IMAP
   - CALDAV
   - CARDDAV
   - EAS settings for hotmail

Comment: In moving from stone age to bronze age is making the live.com work in IMAP mode.

Comment: I agree. That was a big step. It only took MS 30 years to make that leap.

Comment: Apple is going to FAIL so badly when lack of ActiveSync on Mac OS breaks down the much touted 'continuity' feature across iOS and Mac OS.